# Expand/collapse div on click for multiple div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have created the expand/collapse div and its working fine when there is single content `div` when I have multiple its expanding/collapsing all, how do I have it working for individual content div?

Following is the code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 var $divView = $(".added-msg-inner");
 var innerHeight = $divView.removeClass("added-msg-inner").height();
 $divView.addClass('added-msg-inner');
 $(".downarrow").click(function() {
      $(".added-msg-inner").animate({
          height: (($divView.height() == 75)? innerHeight  : "75px")
        }, 500);
  if($(".added-msg-inner").height() == 75){
    $('.downarrow > i').attr("class","fa fa-angle-up");
  }
  else{
 $('.downarrow > i').attr("class","fa fa-angle-down");
  }
        return false;
    });
});
```

```css
.added-msg2 {
 padding: 3% 1%;
 float: left;
 width: 100%;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 font-size: 14px;
 color: #333333;
 position: relative;
 background-color: #e0e0e0;
}
.added-msg-inner {
 float: left;
 width: 100%;
 height: 75px;
 overflow: hidden;
  margin-bottom:15px;
}
.downarrow {
 position: absolute;
 right: 15px;
 bottom: -12px;
 z-index: 1;
 width: 30px;
 height: 30px;
 line-height: 30px;
 font-size: 18px;
 color: #fff;
 background-color: #003478;
 border-radius: 50%;
 text-align: center;
 font-weight: bold;
 cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.1/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-xs-12 lt-grey-bg mar-bot-25">
      <div class="added-msg2">
            <div class="added-msg-inner">
            <p>Message added by agent user on<br>
              Sat, Jun 24th, 2017 (5:03AM)</p>
            <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries</p>
            <p><i class="fa fa-paperclip" aria-hidden="true"></i> ABCFileName.pdf</p>
            </div>
            <div class="downarrow"><i class="fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 lt-grey-bg mar-bot-25">
      <div class="added-msg2">
            <div class="added-msg-inner">
            <p>Message added by agent user on<br>
              Sat, Jun 24th, 2017 (5:03AM)</p>
            <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries</p>
            <p><i class="fa fa-paperclip" aria-hidden="true"></i> ABCFileName.pdf</p>
            </div>
            <div class="downarrow"><i class="fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to make the selectors catch the elements that belong to the same part as the clicked item. Also, the `innerHeight` and `$divView` are no longer single values. I would suggest storing the calculated innerHeights in a data property of the related `$divView` element:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Store inner height in a data property:
    $(".added-msg-inner").removeClass("added-msg-inner").each(function () {
        $(this).data({innerHeight: $(this).height() });
    }).addClass('added-msg-inner');

    $(".downarrow").click(function() {
        // Get specific divView and innerHeight related to this down arrow
        var $divView = $(this).siblings(".added-msg-inner");
        var innerHeight = $divView.data("innerHeight");

        $divView.animate({
            height: $divView.height() == 75 ? innerHeight : "75px"
        }, 500);
        $('i', this).attr("class", 
            $divView.height() == 75 ? "fa fa-angle-up"
                                    : "fa fa-angle-down");
        return false;
    });
});
```